# test the TCP channel created via adb

Tags: android, tcp, adb, netstat

I have created a TCP channel  like:

```
adb forward tcp:5000 tcp:6000
adb reverse tcp:6000 tcp:7000
```

I wanted to send a text massage from my android device and see it on my host.

I have no access to `netcat`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So what's the question?
Tip: to create TCP-connection via USB you need to:

1. Enable "Developer options" > "**USB Debugging**" on your device (so that adbd started working, it will imitate TCP connection over USB);
2. **Forward/reverse** TCP port (depends on what is going to be the server);
3. So that you could use network connection you should add to your Android app manifest permission: **android.permission.INTERNET**
4. Implement server/client logic on the device;

Android app should attempt to create socket via "localhost" and forwarded port. On the PC you should use adb.exe to open the incoming/outgoing connection;